# 'File not found' error when running an execute shell script using Steamcmd

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to automate my build uploads to Steam using Jenkins to transfer the builds from Unity Cloud Build service. However when running this code through a shell script in Jenkins:

```
/sdk/tools/ContentBuilder/builder_linux/steamcmd.sh +login your_login_name +run_app_build $WORKSPACE/app_build_123456.vdf +exit
```

I get this returned:

> ```
> /sdk/tools/ContentBuilder/builder_linux/steamcmd.sh: not found
> ```

The file exists in the Steamworks SDK folder as I have verified many times, yet it can't be found. What is wrong with the file path for it not to be seen by Jenkins?

Comment: Are you sure this is the script that runs actually? The error msg shows a different path.

Comment: That was an error on my part, I have confirmed this is what is returned and corrected it.